# JavaScript: Create Object given .map() input arguments without using ES6 {} Shortcut

Tags: javascript, function, object, arguments, key-value

I am currently using JavaScript ES6 to create the following output object from a .map array method.

```
const indexAndValue = (arr) => {

  return arr.map((elem, index) => {
    return { index, elem }
  }); 
}

indexAndValue([22, 33, 44, 55])
```

The output code is:

```
[ { index: 0, elem: 22 },
  { index: 1, elem: 33 },
  { index: 2, elem: 44 },
  { index: 3, elem: 55 } ]
```

How do I get the same output without using  the {} shortcut?  I tried the following code:

```
const indexAndValue = (arr) => {

  let obj = {}; 

  return arr.map((elem, index) => {
    return obj[index] = elem; 
  }); 
}

indexAndValue([22, 33, 44, 55])
```

This code returns incorrectly:

```
[ 22, 33, 44, 55 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the declaration of object inside of the callback. If outside, you reuse the object and all elements contains the same object, with the latest update, because of the same object reference.

```js
const indexAndValue = (arr) => {
  return arr.map((elem, index) => {
      var object = {};
      object.index = index;
      object.elem = elem;
    return object;
  }); 
}

console.log(indexAndValue([22, 33, 44, 55]));
```

Comment: thank u; so I can better understand: why does the declaration of object need to be inside of callback?

Comment: because if you put it outside it would be the same object for every instance. Try it and see what happens.